# Passing a paremeter taken from a dataframe column to a pandas method

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe with two columns, a naive date, and it's corresponding timezone. I'd like to convert the naive date to a timezone aware date using the second column.

| naive_date | timezone |
| --- | --- |
| 24-01-2021 05:00:00 | 'Europe/London' |
| 24-01-2021 06:00:00 | 'Europe/Amsterdam' |
| 24-01-2021 00:00:00 | 'US/Eastern' |

If I just wanted to convert to a known timezone, I would do:

`df['naive_date'].dt.tz_localize(tz='Europe/London')`

But what if the value passed to tz should be taken from the timezone column for that particular row? Is that possible? I tried, which unsurprisingly didn't work:

`df['naive_date'].dt.tz_localize(tz=df['timezone'])`

For context I'll be comparing the date against another timezone aware date column, and the comparison returns false when comparing naive to timezone aware datetime.

Comment: I usually do this with df.apply(convert_my_tz, axis='columns'), are you open to using apply, or do you wish to use the vectorized correlate?

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: x['naive_date'].dt.tz_localize(tz=x['timezone']), axis = 1)`? (I have not tested it)

Comment: Thanks both, I will look into using apply, it looks promising!

Answer (score 0):

Pablo's answer was spot on, this is what I ended up using:

df['local_date'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['naive_date'].tz_localize(tz=x['timezone']), axis=1)